# Why response sent two headers?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

Hi I have problem with my code. When i run ajax call it throws error:
**local.ERROR: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected** When i check networks i can really see that response header data are duplicated.

Weird is that when i just copy ajax adress from network on other window everything is okay and it returns data as i expect.

I have this ajax method

```
 getReceipts(text)
            {

                $.ajax({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: '/api/invoices/get-receipts',
                    data:text
                }).done((response) => {
                    console.log(response);
                    let newGridItems = [];

                    response.forEach(function(item){
                        item.deal_date = moment(item.deal_date,).format(globalDateFormat_moment);
                        newGridItems.push(item);
                    });
                    this.gridReceiptItems = newGridItems;

                    this.receiptsGridIsBusy = false;

                    if(this.filterCheck)
                    {
                        this.massAddReceipts();
                    }

                });
            },
```

and this laravel method:

```
    public function getReceipts(Request $request)
    {
        $receiptsGrid = new ReceiptsGrid(false);
        $filter = $receiptsGrid->getFilter();
        $grid = $receiptsGrid->getGrid();

        $receiptsGrid = $receiptsGrid->getFilteredToQuery()->withCount('scans')->get();
        //dd($receiptsGrid) -> HERE ALL DATA ARE OKAY
        return $receiptsGrid;
    }
```

Full response:

```
{
    "message": "Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected",
    "exception": "ErrorException",
    "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php",
    "line": 341,
    "trace": [
        {
            "function": "handleError",
            "class": "Barryvdh\\Debugbar\\LaravelDebugbar",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php",
            "line": 341,
            "function": "header"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php",
            "line": 375,
            "function": "sendHeaders",
            "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Response",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/public/index.php",
            "line": 58,
            "function": "send",
            "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Response",
            "type": "->"
        }
    ]
}
```

Where should by problem please?

Comment: Is it possible that the URL `'/api/invoices/get-receipts'` causes an internal redirect? To find out use your browser developer tools, network tab, and switch persistent logging on.